# Получить среднее число заказов пользователей по годам

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица orders:

```
id_o,user_id,price,o_date
81,1,"539,000",2016-01-01
84,1,"153,300",2016-02-15
87,2,"55,300",2016-03-12
88,2,"752,500",2016-04-19
89,2,"4410,000",2016-05-20
91,1,"539,000",2017-01-01
94,1,"153,300",2017-02-15
97,2,"55,300",2017-03-12
98,2,"752,500",2017-04-19
99,3,"4410,000",2017-05-20
```

Подскажите, как из неё получить среднее число заказов (id_0) по юзерам (user_id) по годам?
В итоге должно получиться две цифры - среднее число заказов на юзера в 2016 и 2017 гг.

Что сделано:

Я получил промежуточную таблицу со количеством заказов на каждого юзера :

```
SELECT COUNT(id_o) FROM orders 
    GROUP BY user_id;
```

Но не понимаю, где и в какой последовательности нужно вставить запрос с уточнением по годам и получить среднее значение по результирующей таблице. В идеале   - подсказать в какой части документации \ какую статью нужно прочитать.

Comment: пишу из головы, но олжно быть как-то так select user_id, count(o_date)/(year(max(o_date))-year(min(o_date)+1) from orders  group by user_id

Answer (score 2):

чтобы посчитать среднее число заказов на юзера надо общее число заказов разделить на число уникальных юзеров, то есть `COUNT/COUNT DISTINCT`

```
SELECT YEAR(o_date)
     , (COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS avg
FROM t
WHERE o_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
GROUP BY YEAR(o_date)
```

Comment: етить, архаизм из ленты попался какой-то

Answer (score 0):

Для расчета среднего нужно воспользоваться функцией `avg`.

```sql
select user_id, avg(id_o) as avg
from orders
where user_id = 153
group by year(o_date)
```

Главное здесь извлечь год из даты `year(o_date)`.

Расчета среднего по всем пользователям:

```sql
select user_id, avg(id_o) over (PARTITION BY user_id) as avg
from orders
group by year(o_date)
```

Это будет работать в MariaDb / PostgreSql поздних версиях.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, здесь мы получаем ответ по конкретному пользователю, а не по всем пользователям?

Comment: Да, это по конкретному пользователю. Если делать в один запрос для всех - будет дорого в плане ресурсов.

Comment: Но нужно-то СРЕДНЕЕ число заказов по всем юзерам, а не число заказов одного конкретного юзера по годам...

Comment: Тогда там нужно заменить `price` на `id_o` и должно заработать.

Comment: На выходе вы ожидаете видеть ГОД, Среднее по заказам, верно ?

Comment: Верно. Я подправил вопрос.